# how to deattach multidimentional json in php

Tags: php, json

i need some help here.
basically i want 3different objects data in my json.

when i catch it in php, i will exactly get 3 object data. 
and i will looping it in my function. i need to show eachh data in that object. but i dont know how. please show me the way.

here is the json data:

> [{"30":"2016-09-01"},{"07":"2016-09-24"},{"03":"2016-09-28"}]

when i count in php it will show that the objects are 3.

```
echo $json_encode = count(json_decode($json_encode));
```

but how can i get the data?
i want to get and read the "30" and the values "2016-09-01"

how can i do that things?

many thanks returs in advance.

Comment: what are you counting? ... counting an array which is the data

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` returns an array when the second parameter is set to `TRUE` so just use a foreach loop

```
$json_encode = json_decode($json_encode, TRUE);

foreach($json_encode as $key => $value){
    //'30' would be in $key
    //'2016-09-01' would be in $value
}
```

You need to assign or use these variables inside the loop

Comment: *"json_decode returns an array"*...not entirely accurate

Comment: @cha Sorry, I've corrected my answer now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) here.

Try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

So, JSON is converted to array, and `$array` becomes:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [30] => 2016-09-01
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [07] => 2016-09-24
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [03] => 2016-09-28
    )
)
```

Now, we need to loop through `$array`

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        echo "Value corresponding to $k is - $v";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value corresponding to 30 is - 2016-09-01
Value corresponding to 07 is - 2016-09-24
Value corresponding to 03 is - 2016-09-28
```

Comment: If I read it correctly, it was mentioned that they wanted to access 30 and  2016-09-01..and so on.